# Can I convert current JAXB model to other JAXB model?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have two XML files `file1.xml` and `file2.xml`. I also have schemas for each of these files, `file1.xsd` and `file2.xsd` respectfully.

I use `xjc` to create java classes based on `file1.xsd` (called model(1)), and to create classes based on `file2.xsd` (called model(2)).

I use model(1) to unmarshal file1.xml with the `JAXB` library. I want to convert this data from model(1) to model(2) and then marshal the converted data to `file2.xml`

Is it possible to convert data from model(1) to model(2) ? Can I merge `ObjectFactories`? How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your use case there isn't a way to automatically convert from a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) model generated from one XML schema to another JAXB model generated from another XML schema.  There are a few options:

**OPTION #1 - Object-to-Object Conversions**

You could programatically move the data between object models.  There are also mapping libraries that can make this process easier (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

**OPTION #2 - XSLT**

XSLT is the standard for converting one XML document to another based on a set of rules.  With the use of `JAXBSource` and `JAXBResult` you can even use XSLT on Java models.

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream("my-xslt.xml"));
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(xslt);

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext1, foo);
JAXBResult result = new JAXBResult(jaxbContext2);
t.transform(source, result);
Bar bar = (Bar) result.getResult();
```

**OPTION #3 - EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)'s External Mapping File**

I'm the MOXy lead and we offer an external mapping file that allows you to map an object model to multiple XML representations.  See the link below for an example:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure I understand the question - I think what you need is to add a constructor on your Model2 class which accept a Model1 class as a parameter.

As an example, let's say this is your Model1 class:

```
class Model1{
    String firstname;
    String surname;

}

class Model2{
    String fullName
    public Model2(Model1 m){
        this.fullname=m.firstname+" "+m.surname;
    }
}
```

ie inside that constructor, copy the values of the attributes from m to the Model2 instance

After that you can convert between Model1 and Model2:

```
Model1 m1=unmarshall("file1.xml");
Model2 m2=new Model2(m1);
m2.marshall("file2.xml");
```

If you are going through all this effort only to convert between xml formats, I would recommend you use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) instead.